# Graph Sortability C++

Tags: c++, graph, theory

So I've got a homework problem:

> Let `G` be a directed graph on `n` vertices.
>
> Call `G` sortable if the vertices can be distinctly numbered from `1` to `n` (no two vertices have the same number) such that each vertex with incoming edges has at least one predecessor with a lower number. For example, Let `NUM(v)` be the number assigned to vertex `v` and consider a vertex `x` with incoming edges from three other vertices `r`, `y`, and `z`. Then `NUM(x)` must be bigger than at least one of `NUM(r)`, `NUM(y)`, and `NUM(z)`.

Furthermore the algorithm must be linear; `O(|V|+|E|)`.

---

Traversing the graph is easy enough but I have no idea how to check the parents of the vertex to see if the num of **any** of the parents are lower than that of the child.

How should I keep reference of the parents of the vertex I'm on?

---

The following adjacency lists are input files (Just samples the actual test cases have around 8k vertices).

```
1->2
2->3
3->1

Is not Sortable.

1->2
2->3
3->4
4->2

Is Sortable.
```

---

The problem can be in done in C++/C and I've chosen C++ for use of STL.

I store the graph using adjacency lists, the input files are edge lists.

Comment: Try and highlight the specific troubles that you are having. Obviously we will not do your homework for you but we are happy to help clear specific stumbling blocks.

Comment: @Veedrac Thank you my post looks much nicer now, I'm primarily having issues looking back to the parents of the vertex I'm on (Not sure of a better way to state this).

Comment: Don't you mean you've chosen C++ for STL?

Comment: @MarceloCantos That is indeed what I meant, the correction has been made.

Comment: I've considered (And began attempting) to use a modified DFS to accomplish the task, however it leaves me questioning how to determine if one of the parents has a lower numValue;

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it?

1. Create an adjacency matrix. If `row` points to `col`, then put a `1`
   there.
2. Scan down each `col` to the first `1`. If `col` <= `row` then `fail`.
3. Otherwise, `pass`.

Here are the tables for your two examples:

```
  1 2 3
1 0 1 0
2 0 0 1
3 1 0 0

  1 2 3 4
1 0 1 0 0
2 0 0 1 0
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 0
```

If you are worried about space because it has to handle 8k vertices, then you can use a sparse representation if you know the input is sparse. But really, I think 64M ints should not be cause for concern.

GCC 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x sortable-graph.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string trim(const std::string& str) {
  std::string s;
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  ss >> s;
  return s;
}

using graph = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

graph read(std::istream& is) {
  graph G;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> edges;
  std::map<std::string, int> labels;
  int max = -1;

  // Assume input is a list of edge definitions, one per line. Each line is:
  // "label -> label" where white space is optional, "->" is a literal, and
  // "label" does not contain "->" or white space.

  // This can be vastly simplified if we can assume sensible int labels.

  std::string l;
  while (std::getline(is, l)) {
    // Parse the labels.
    const auto n = l.find("->");
    const auto lhs = trim(l.substr(0, n));
    const auto rhs = trim(l.substr(n + 2));

    // Convert the labels to ints.
    auto i = labels.find(lhs);
    if (i == labels.end()) { labels[lhs] = ++max; }
    auto j = labels.find(rhs);
    if (j == labels.end()) { labels[rhs] = ++max; }

    // Remember the edge.
    edges.push_back({labels[lhs], labels[rhs]});
  }

  // Resize the adjacency matrix.
  G.resize(max+1);
  for (auto& v : G) { v.resize(max+1); }

  // Mark the  edges.
  for (const auto& e : edges) { G[e.first][e.second] = 1; }

  return G;
}

bool isSortable(const graph& G) {
  const int s = G.size();
  for (int col = 0; col < s; ++col) {
    for (int row = 0; row < s; ++row) {
      if (G[row][col] == 1) {
        if (col <= row) { return false; }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

void print(std::ostream& os, const graph& G) {
  const int s = G.size();
  for (int row = 0; row < s; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < s; ++col) {
      os << G[row][col] << " ";
    }
    os << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  const auto G = read(std::cin);
  print(std::cout, G);
  const auto b = isSortable(G);

  std::cout << (b ? "Is Sortable.\n" : "Is not Sortable.\n");
}
```

Now that I look at it, I guess this is O(V^2).

Answer (score 0):

Take two! This one is O(|V|+|E|).

GCC 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x sortable-graph.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string trim(const std::string& str) {
  std::string s;
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  ss >> s;
  return s;
}

using edges = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;

void read(std::istream& is, edges& E, int& max) {
  std::map<std::string, int> labels;
  max = -1;

  // Assume input is a list of edge definitions, one per line. Each line is:
  // "label -> label" where white space is optional, "->" is a literal, and
  // "label" does not contain "->" or white space.

  // This can be vastly simplified if we can assume sensible int labels.

  std::string l;
  while (std::getline(is, l)) {
    // Parse the labels.
    const auto n = l.find("->");
    const auto lhs = trim(l.substr(0, n));
    const auto rhs = trim(l.substr(n + 2));

    // Convert the labels to ints.
    auto i = labels.find(lhs);
    if (i == labels.end()) { labels[lhs] = ++max; }
    auto j = labels.find(rhs);
    if (j == labels.end()) { labels[rhs] = ++max; }

    // Remember the edge.
    E.push_back({labels[lhs], labels[rhs]});
  }
}

bool isSortable(const edges& E, int max) {
  std::vector<int> num(max+1, max+1);
  for (const auto& e : E) {
    num[e.second] = std::min(e.first, num[e.second]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); ++i) {
    if (num[i] != max + 1 && i <= num[i]) { return false; }
  }

  return true;
}

int main() {
  edges E;
  int max;
  read(std::cin, E, max);
  const auto b = isSortable(E, max);

  std::cout << (b ? "Is Sortable.\n" : "Is not Sortable.\n");
}
```